# "The CSRF token is invalid" on autogenerated Symfony 6 registration form

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I'm trying to create user authentication in my Symfony 6 project. I have everything set up - the User entity with its Doctrine database migration, the project database with the required tables, the user registration field automatically generated by `bin/console make:user-registration`-- but I'm always getting the following error:

```
The CSRF token is invalid. Please try resubmitting the form.
```

I have tried several things - starting everything from scratch, using the default, unedited User entity that is autogenerated, manually including the CSRF field, using a self-signed SSL certificate, in case HTTP was at fault - nothing has worked.

I'll add the code snippets, in case you good folk need to check them (even though they are autogenerated).

**/src/Controller/RegistrationController.php**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\User;
use App\Form\RegistrationFormType;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\PasswordHasher\Hasher\UserPasswordHasherInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class RegistrationController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/register', name: 'app_register')]
    public function register(Request $request, UserPasswordHasherInterface $userPasswordHasher, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager): Response
    {
        $user = new User();
        $form = $this->createForm(RegistrationFormType::class, $user);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            // encode the plain password
            $user->setPassword(
                $userPasswordHasher->hashPassword(
                    $user,
                    $form->get('plainPassword')->getData()
                )
            );

            $entityManager->persist($user);
            $entityManager->flush();
            // do anything else you need here, like send an email

            return $this->redirectToRoute('_preview_error');
        }

        return $this->render('registration/register.html.twig', [
            'registrationForm' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }
}
```

**src/Form/RegistrationFormType.php**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CheckboxType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\PasswordType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\IsTrue;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Length;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank;

class RegistrationFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('username')
            ->add('agreeTerms', CheckboxType::class, [
                'mapped' => false,
                'constraints' => [
                    new IsTrue([
                        'message' => 'You should agree to our terms.',
                    ]),
                ],
            ])
            ->add('plainPassword', PasswordType::class, [
                // instead of being set onto the object directly,
                // this is read and encoded in the controller
                'mapped' => false,
                'attr' => ['autocomplete' => 'new-password'],
                'constraints' => [
                    new NotBlank([
                        'message' => 'Please enter a password',
                    ]),
                    new Length([
                        'min' => 6,
                        'minMessage' => 'Your password should be at least {{ limit }} characters',
                        // max length allowed by Symfony for security reasons
                        'max' => 4096,
                    ]),
                ],
            ])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => User::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

**templates/registration/register.html.twig**

```php
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Register{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <h1>Register</h1>

    {{ form_errors(registrationForm) }}

    {{ form_start(registrationForm) }}
        {{ form_row(registrationForm.username, {
            icon: "icons/user.svg"
        }) }}
        {{ form_row(registrationForm.plainPassword, {
            label: 'Password'
        }) }}
        {{ form_row(registrationForm.agreeTerms) }}

        <button type="submit" class="btn">Register</button>
    {{ form_end(registrationForm) }}
{% endblock %}
```

I *am* using a custom Form theme, but that shouldn't cause the issue, especially considering that the CSRF token still gets nicely passed into the final HTML that gets sent to the user.

**The compiled HTML form:**

```html
<form method="post" name="registration_form">
  <div>
    <label class="block required text-gray-800" for="registration_form_username"
      >Username</label
    >
    <div
      class="bg-grey-950 border border-secondary-light fill-white flex flex-row focus-within:border-primary focus-within:outline-primary focus-within:ring-1 focus-within:ring-offset-1 focus-within:ring-primary-light placeholder-grey px-6 py-3 rounded shadow-md text-white w-full"
    >
      <div class="-ml-4 -my-1 fill-white flex icon items-center pr-2">
        <svg fill="currentColor" height="32" viewBox="0 0 256 256" width="32">
          <!-- SVG icon data here -->
        </svg>
      </div>
      <input name="username" type="text"
        required maxlength="90" 
        class="bg-transparent border-0 focus:border-transparent focus:ring-0 focus:ring-offset-0 outline-none p-0 w-full"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="registration_form_plainPassword"
      class="block required text-gray-800"
      >Password</label
    >
    <div
      class="bg-grey-950 border border-secondary-light fill-white flex flex-row focus-within:border-primary focus-within:outline-primary focus-within:ring-1 focus-within:ring-offset-1 focus-within:ring-primary-light placeholder-grey px-6 py-3 rounded shadow-md text-white w-full"
    >
      <div class="-ml-4 -my-1 fill-white flex icon items-center pr-2">
        <svg fill="currentColor" height="32" viewBox="0 0 256 256" width="32">
          <!-- SVG icon data here -->
        </svg>
      </div>
      <input name="plainPassword" type="password"
        required autocomplete="new-password"
        class="bg-transparent border-0 focus:border-transparent focus:ring-0 focus:ring-offset-0 outline-none p-0 w-full"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="mb-6">
    <div class="inline-flex items-center">
      <input id="registration_form_agreeTerms" name="registration_form[agreeTerms]"
        type="checkbox" value="1" required
        class="mr-2"
      />
      <label for="registration_form_agreeTerms"
        class="block required text-gray-800"
        >Agree terms</label
      >
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="btn" type="submit">Register</button>
  <div>
    <input name="_token" type="hidden"
      value="3b091c63ffd73f7851594efa3a99f8.XXbsDPuiFYQ0X7OklSp7vPxLO_BUr3GaUZhOCGwZEUc.JAycZ6jIbdJWDOf18mQKha8DfL8G9gL7CPQfXCZMYyMIEK4-ltVA6l8H9g"
    />
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: What is your exact symfony version ?

Comment: composer.json says 6.3

Answer (score 1):

Well, it appears that it actually *was* the fault of my form theme. I forgot to add the id and name properties in my blocks:

```
{% block form_widget_simple %}
    {# ...content here... #}
    <input
        id="{{ id }}"
        name="{{ full_name }}"
        type="{{ type }}"

        {# ...other attributes here... #}
    />
    {# ...content here... #}
{% endblock form_widget_simple %}

{% block checkbox_widget %}
    <input
        id="{{ id }}"
        name="{{ full_name }}"
        type="radio"

        {# ...other attributes here... #}
    />
{% endblock checkbox_widget %}

{% block radio_widget %}
    <input
        id="{{ id }}"
        name="{{ full_name }}"
        type="radio"

        {# ...other attributes here... #}
    />
{% endblock radio_widget %}

{% block button_widget %}
    {# ...content here... #}
    <button
        id="{{ id }}"
        name="{{ full_name }}"
        type="{{ type }}"

        {# ...other attributes here... #}
    >
        {# ...content here... #}
    </button>
    {# ...content here... #}
{% endblock button_widget %}
```